# Typescript mapped type error when type is annotated

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Not sure if the title is explicit (it was not easyto describe this issue in one sentence) but here is some code to illustrate the issue (more details about the issue after the code block):

```js
type AttributeDefinition = {
    name:string
    type: 'string' | 'number',

}
type EntityDefinition = {
    attributes: Readonly<AttributeDefinition[]>
}

export type Entity<ET extends EntityDefinition> = {
    [K in ET['attributes'][number] as K['name']]:
    K['type'] extends 'string' ? string :
    K['type'] extends 'number' ? number :
    never
}

const def1 = {
    attributes: [
        {name:'foo', type: 'string'},
        {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
    ] as const
}

const def2: EntityDefinition = {
    attributes: [
        {name:'foo', type: 'string'},
        {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
    ] as const
}

const entity1: Entity<typeof def1> = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 42
}

const entity2: Entity<typeof def2> = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 42
}
```

So my issue is that typescript throw an error on `entity2` when I want to assign `'bar'` to `foo` (and `42` to `baz`). The issue is `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

However, this issue does not occurs with `entity1`.

The origin of this issue seems to be related to the declaration of `def2` for which I annotate the `EntityDefinition` type. I am doing this so I can have typing hint from my IDE helping me to properly declare the `def2` object.

But the `def1` object, even if not type annotated, is later properly handled when creating the `entity1`, whereas `def2` (that I would expect to be typed the right way) fails when it is used to create the `entity2`.

I am not really sure to understand why it does fail in such a way, and how can I annotate a object as I do for `def2` and also use such an object later as I do for `entity1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `Entity<typeof def2>` fails is that the annotation widens the type of `def2`, which causes the specifics to get lost. The type of `Entity<typeof def2>` is equal to `Entity<EntityDefinition>`, which evaluates to `{[x: string]: never}`.

You could probably create a generic type annotation that preserves the information, but then you'd have to specify the generic parameters in the constant type, which would lead to duplicated code.

On approach to deal with this is to create a constructor function that just returns the argument but has a constraint on it:

```
const mkEntityDefinition = <T extends EntityDefinition>(def: T) => def
```

You can use it like this:

```
const def3 = mkEntityDefinition({
    attributes: [
        {name:'foo', type: 'string'},
        {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
    ] as const
})

export const entity3: Entity<typeof def3> = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 42
}
```

and it will prevent mistakes:

```
const defBad = mkEntityDefinition({
    attributes: [ 
        {name:'foo', type: 'strrring'},
        {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
    ] as const
})
// Error: Type '"strrring"' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number"'.
// Did you mean '"string"'?
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4T)

Answer (score 2):

Until the time that [`satifies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71608938/438273) makes it into TS, you can use a constrained identity function to provide IntelliSense assistance while physically typing your definition in your editor, while still allowing the compiler to infer its (more specific) literal properties:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAgswCcCWAjArsCARCAzJAdksEgPYFQC8UA3gFBRQECGAthAFwDOihA5gG4GUUJA5QA5D2QE+EqAB9JBNKxQQEEoQF8hdUdACiBEqBz4iJclVrDm8ZOkxdxCCMwAm5ADYhYD1AxsPEJiMgIAbQBdHT1cNAIAYysKRLd7CGNTEHNQlKgAHgAVKAgAD0wCDy4oLOIckMtwgD4ACg88cSKASi7bRjdgNAQKDtwdOjpysFIEYBFwIxN6gsMS8srq2uWzRrDyZpt6RgiAaShCWqKIiXteJwguCSiIlTUNKKhmGtOblnZnlEOMJGL8JAZnqUKhAqjUpLxZPIAPxQaT8EFQcRgiGfDYwrYSN7qTRQFFEjQY8QECAANw0sUmiXIPCgYwAjDY0u5MHVdhZ9gRWscvgEHi4oBEMTR-pwJLhSKQJAAaBZiSRoxHaJVSmUcCQoZgAL2Vqs4ylUxIkWuEn2+UCZBB42u03T0DpZYwATJz0jydg1+SkhXZRUFxZLGIxpWxZfLFSqDOJ4TI5NbI7RdfqjSbE+b3po01BbTV3cBna7Gcz5jDsmzxLyQAUDKRcKy8GzDtRhXGkwbNNrGAbDeIACye51uqulf2e+v+puLFtt3Cezv9KA9yR95XCIej8d0XR0IA)

```ts
function createEntityDefinition <T extends EntityDefinition>(def: T): T {
  return def;
}

const def2 = createEntityDefinition({
  attributes: [
    {name:'foo', type: 'string'},
    {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
  ] as const,
});

const entity2: Entity<typeof def2> = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 42,
}; // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an upcoming feature addressing this specific use case: ["satisfies" operator to ensure an expression matches some type (feedback reset) #47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920)

```ts
const def2 = {
    attributes: [
        {name:'foo', type: 'string'},
        {name:'baz', type: 'number'},
    ] as const
} satisfies EntityDefinition;
```

It is still under development, but you can check a working example at [Staging Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.7.0-pr-46827-30#code/C4TwDgpgBAgswCcCWAjArsCARCAzJAdksEgPYFQC8UA3gFBSNQECGAthAFwDOihA5gyahInKAHJeyAv3FQAPhIJo2KCAnF0AvnTojoAUQIlQOfERLkqtIYxbxk6TNzEAlCCwAm5ADYgAPHB8Tth4hMRkBADaALoAfNq6EAAeYKQIwFD6UEYmAQYAKlApmASe3DnGxCBm4ZYEcdb0TFBRANJQhDkFUeL2wRgQ3OIxUcqq6jFQLBVtvawcIzGctlBz4vojxcml5RJSAnIA-FAHMlArLeubUyUQZRXi42oaUCfP6herBBAAbuqJOgAY3IvCgnjwAEYmqt+o5Bi5WqsWjQFlxxLhSKRxAAaLLgLj7PgycRaHHIpio9jolAsABeuPxoiUKhepPJLSmMygIIIvEBvLBENwACYYS04agEWIohTGFSOJwMVjGfoxJJibIyXLaGilbSGXi1SyJhptZzphVBcBtKd7EhuPghpU8rULJFdNbilVQJCxLlqv59KRcOCoY1qM0mJjSOraRoOUwDWIACwigWgzL3PIi-0+gLB0PCkURmwtGNxlgJ1bJqBp7RAA)